# JavaFX: How to stroke only certain areas of a GridPane (or other structure)

Tags: css, javafx, outline, stroke

I want to create a table-like structure and stroke the borders and just some of the inner lines to help guide the viewer's eye.  This is just a snippet of a much larger structure to help illustrate the goal:

[click to view sample here](http://www.dterryphotography.com/photos/i-rgGMvgf/0/X3/i-rgGMvgf-X3.png)

I am currently using GridPane rather than TableView because this structure is both input/output.  The user will need to view the information and update some of the numbers on the screen.

The trouble is that turning gridlines on for the entire structure becomes very noisy visually. So instead I want to use CSS to only put lines around certain elements within the GridPane.

But then with CSS I run into a complex mess. For example the ward1 cell needs to be stroked on the left, top and bottom.  The ward2 cell needs to be stroked on just the top and bottom, same for ward3 ... the ward7 cell needs top, right and bottom and so on.

Is there a better way to do this - either with CSS, or with a better layout, that would make it easier to stroke just the parts of the grid that I want stroked?

(currently using Java 1.7.0_40-b43 and Scene Builder 1.1)

Comment: try this -fx-background-color: black, white; -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 1 1; where for each inset are given in the order top, right, bottom, left.

Answer (score 0):

A GridPane doesn't generate cells like a TableView or ListView. It is basically just a Pane with special constraints for the nodes you add to it. Unfortunately, this means creating your own cells and applying styles to them which can get very messy.

With some planning and some helper methods, it is possible to keep things somewhat tidy. The following generates a GridPane with styles similar to the example image provided using StackPanes as cells. I only used labels, so you would have to replace with TextFields or whatever controls you are using for input. This code is just to demonstrate one way to keep things orderly.

Note that rotating labels will not rotate their bounds and therefore will not behave as expected within GridPane constraints, so in this case, it is best to put them in a Group first:

```
    public static void main(final String... a) {
        Application.launch(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
        grid.setVgap(0); 
        grid.setHgap(0);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        
        ColumnConstraints column = new ColumnConstraints();
        column.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        column.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
        column.setFillWidth(true);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(column);
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            column = new ColumnConstraints();
            column.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
            column.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(column);
        }
        
        // row 0
        addCell(grid, 1, 0, 7, 1, "Ward/Branch Actual", Pos.CENTER, true, false, false, false);
        addCell(grid, 8, 0, 3, 1, "Current Qtr", Pos.CENTER, true, false, false, false);
        addCell(grid, 11, 0, 2, 1, "Stake Totals", Pos.CENTER, true, false, false, false);
        
        // row 1
        addCell(grid, 0, 1, 1, 1, "Members/Families", Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT, true, true, false, false);
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            addVerticalCell(grid, i, 1, "Ward " + i, (i == 7));
        }
        addVerticalCell(grid, 8,  1, "Actual", false);
        addVerticalCell(grid, 9,  1, "Potential", false);
        addVerticalCell(grid, 10, 1, "%", true);
        addVerticalCell(grid, 11, 1, "% 1 year ago", false);
        addVerticalCell(grid, 12, 1, "% 5 years ago", true);
        
        // row 2
        addDividerRow(grid, 2);
        
        // row 3
        addCell(grid, 0, 3, 1, 1, "Total Members", Pos.CENTER_LEFT, false, true, true, true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            addCell(grid, i, 3, 1, 1, "78%", Pos.CENTER, false, (i == 7 || i == 10 || i == 12), true, true);
        }
        
        // row 4
        addCell(grid, 0, 4, 1, 1, "Total Families", Pos.CENTER_LEFT, false, true, false, false);
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            addCell(grid, i, 4, 1, 1, "83%", Pos.CENTER, false, (i == 7 || i == 10 || i == 12), false, false);
        }
        
        // row 5
        addDividerRow(grid, 5);
        
        final Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 1000, 700);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("styles/style.css"); // or wherever you put it
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Styled GridPane Test");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    private void addCell(GridPane grid, int col, int row, int cspan, int rspan, String text, Pos pos, boolean isBold, boolean hasRightBorder, boolean hasBottomBorder, boolean isShaded) {
        Label label = new Label(text);
        if (isBold) {
            label.getStyleClass().add("h1");
        }
        StackPane spane = new StackPane(label);
        spane.setAlignment(pos);
        if (hasBottomBorder && hasRightBorder) {
            spane.getStyleClass().addAll("bd", "bdrb");
        } else if (hasBottomBorder && !hasRightBorder) {
            spane.getStyleClass().addAll("bd", "bdb");
        } else if (!hasBottomBorder && hasRightBorder) {
            spane.getStyleClass().addAll("bd", "bdr");
        }
        if (isShaded) {
            spane.getStyleClass().addAll("shaded");
        }
        grid.add(spane, col, row, cspan, rspan);
    }
    
    private void addVerticalCell(GridPane grid, int col, int row, String text, boolean hasRightBorder){
        Label label = new Label(text);
        Group group = new Group(label);
        StackPane spane = new StackPane(group);
        spane.getStyleClass().addAll("vert", "bd");
        if (hasRightBorder) {
            spane.getStyleClass().add("bdtr");
        } else {
            spane.getStyleClass().add("bdt");
        }
        grid.add(spane, col, row, 1, 1);
    }
    
    private void addDividerRow(GridPane grid, int row) {
        StackPane stack_0_2 = new StackPane();
        stack_0_2.getStyleClass().addAll("bd", "divider");
        grid.add(stack_0_2, 0, row, 1, 1);
        StackPane stack_1_2 = new StackPane();
        stack_1_2.getStyleClass().addAll("bd", "divider");
        grid.add(stack_1_2, 1, row, 7, 1);
        StackPane stack_1_8 = new StackPane();
        stack_1_8.getStyleClass().addAll("bd", "divider");
        grid.add(stack_1_8, 8, row, 3, 1);
        StackPane stack_1_11 = new StackPane();
        stack_1_11.getStyleClass().addAll("bd", "divider");
        grid.add(stack_1_11, 11, row, 2, 1);
    }
```

```
/*
    style.css
 */
.root {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    -fx-padding: 4px;
}
.label {
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
}
.h1 {
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
.vert {
    -fx-alignment: BOTTOM_CENTER;
}
.vert .label {
    -fx-rotate: -90;
}
.bd {
    -fx-border-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    -fx-border-width: 1;
}
.bdt {
    -fx-border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}
.bdtr {
    -fx-border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
}
.bdr {
    -fx-border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
}
.bdrb {
    -fx-border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
.bdb {
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
}
.divider {
    -fx-border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    -fx-padding: 2px;
}
.shaded {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}
```